# No Variables or Call Stack in Flutter DevTools when running app on Chrome (web) or Edge (web)

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

I cannot get the Variables and Call Stack areas to populate in Flutter DevTools when running apps on Chrome (web) or Edge (web).
A few tabs along the top are not showing either.
Also, DevTools does not automatically open main.dart but opens web_entrypoint.dart.

These areas/tabs do populate/show when running the apps on an android device - virtual and physical. And DevTools automatically opens main.dart.

Is this normal?

**Issue:** [Apps running on Chrome/Edge (Web)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJnSW.png)

**No issue:** [Apps running on a physical/virtual android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaDfD.png)

I do have a mismatch between the version of dart detected when I run
Get dependencies - "The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-377.0.dev" - and when I run the command 'dart --version' - "Dart SDK version: 2.17.3 (stable)". Though I don't think this is likely to be related to my DevTools issue.

Comment: Are you running `dart devtools`?

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Isn't Flutter DevTools the same / another name for Dart DevTools?

Comment: Yes.  If you run it from the command line it will show you the url to listen to.  If you are using VSCode or IntelliJ the process to figure out what is wrong will be different.  The OS you are running might make a difference too.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Sorry I'm not sure I understand. My issue is not how to start/connect to Flutter/Dart DevTools. My issue is that DevTools only shows me variables and call stack when I run apps on android - physical or virtual (2nd link), but not when I choose chrome/edge (web) as the device to run the apps on.

Comment: You must be stopped on a breakpoint to see those frames.  Have you set one?

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Yes I have. DevTools pauses as it should when hitting a breakpoint, but the step in/step over options remain greyed out, and the variables/call stack areas remain blank.